# How can I find out the correct order of vertices to create a quad face with bmesh?

Tags: python, vertices, bmesh, faces

Let's say I have 4 vertices and want to create a quad face with bmesh.
Is there way to figure out the right order of the vertices to not get a face like this
[image: face with improper vertex order]

But rather a face like this.
[image: face with correct vertex order]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From 4 verts you can construct 6 edges: **throw away 2 longest that don't share a vert** and from there you get the correct vertex order.

Comment: Didn't thought about that! So simple and so genius! Thanks alot!